# Prove that : $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n = L \iff\lim_{n\to \infty}b_n =L $

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

let $a_n$ be a sequence. we define $b_n=a_{n+k}$, $k\in \mathbb {N}$, prove that

$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n = L  \iff \lim_{n\to \infty}b_n =L $

I need to formally prove this, can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Since $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$, that means there's some positive integer $N_a$ such that for all $n \geq N_a$ we have
$|a_n - L| < \epsilon$. Can you find a similar constant for the sequence $\{b_n\}$, call it $N_b$,
in terms of the constant $N_a$?

Comment: can I called it $N_{a+k}$ ?

Comment: That's an okay name, though a more representative choice of notation might be to define $N_b := N_a + k$.

Comment: then I can say for each $\epsilon_1 > 0$ there is $N_b := N_a + k$ s.t for each $n+k > N_b$ $|a_{n+k} -L|<$$\epsilon_1$ ?

Comment: You actually only need $n > N_b$ in that last statement (because $N_b$ already has a $+k$ in its definition), but you have the right idea here.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the limit is that for some $n_0$ and $\epsilon$, $|a_n - L| < \epsilon$ for $n > n_0$.

For the $b$ series, there is also an $n_0$, namely the $n_0$ from the $a$ series + $k$.